# Create 'rgithub' tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

It would be helpful if we had a tag created for the `rgithub` package: https://github.com/cscheid/rgithub

Comment: **Why** would it be helpful? How many questions are there on the subject already? Don't the [tag:r] and [tag:github-api] tags cover this already? Or does the package require specific expertise, so that tagging these questions helps the experts find the questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you defining helpful?  The last I read on such a definition, tags are only deemed useful after they have appeared on at least 40 posts (I'll try and find a citation - I think it was a SO blog post?).

As far as *"rgithub"* is concerned there are only 4 questions mentioning it and 3 of them are yours.  If the library proves popular the tag may be adopted naturally and retroactively applied to your posts so I wouldn't worry about it.